# Can I associate a CODE reference with a HASH reference that contains it in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I want to create a hash reference with code references mapped to scalars (strings) as its members.

So far I have a map reference that looks something like this:

```
my $object;
$object = {
    'code1' => sub {
        print $_[0];
    },
    'code2' => sub {
        return 'Hello, World!';
    },
    'code3' => sub {
        $object->{code1}->($object->{code2}->());
    }
};
$object->{code3}->();
```

I would like to be able to "bless" the 'code3' reference in $object with $object, so I can do something like:

```
my $object;
$object = {
    'code1' => sub {
        print $_[0];
    },
    'code2' => sub {
        return 'Hello, World!';
    },
    'code3' => sub {
        $self = shift;
        $self->{code1}->($self->{code2}->());
    }
};
$object->{code3}->();
```

However, bless only works with packages, rather than hash tables.

Is there a way to do this in Perl 5 version 22?

Note: now that I think of it, it's better to pass $object to the method explicitly, as it solves JavaScript's ["this"](http://www.i-programmer.info/programmer-puzzles/137-javascript/1922-the-this-problem.html) problem. I am just too used to Java's "this" which makes sense in Java where everything is a class and therefore all methods have a "this", but in scripting, it really helps to know if the "this" is actually passed, or is it just called as a function(and you end up accidentally polluting global scope or triggering strict warning) passing $self explicitly makes it clear that you are not calling it as a function, but as a method.

Comment: https://eval.in/639754 (possible memory leak => https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util#weaken)

Comment: @Сухой27 it's lets the scope not be bound to a specific object, so I am free to rename the $object from $object to $object2 without needing to change internal code. I am having a bit of a struggle understanding your second comment. Interesting comment about memory leak though. Circular references in Perl are more problematic than in JavaScript since it uses reference counting, rather than mark and sweep.

Comment: It is possible to end up with hash not being released when `$object` goes out of scope. I'm not sure why you would like to avoid packages; https://eval.in/639768

Comment: @Сухой27 my concern with packages is that I can't seem to create packages at runtime, but I can create hash tables at runtime, so they seem more flexible an easier to inspect. Also, I can't create Perl Object Notation around packages, but I can with maps, so I can serialize objects/deserialize objects but I don't think I can do this with packages since I can't have a function create a package with variable package name. Also, I don't know how to "remove" a package once I declare it, whereas maps can be released when they leave scope.

Comment: You can add package methods at compile time: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28373893/223226 (`'If you don't know the name at compile time'` part)

Comment: You can also just send in the `$object` into your call: `$object->{code3}->($object);`. This'll work, and won't require any internal changes, but if you change the obj name, you'll have to update the name of the param in the sub call

Comment: $stevieb I was considering that, it works but has repeated $object in it which looks funny. It would look stranger if the map was inside three indirections of maps, and you'd need to either create a temporary variable to refer to the $object, or have a duplicate of something like `$object->{object2}->{object3}->{coderef}->($object->{object2}->{object3})`. I guess that's fine with an anonymous scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing sub calls (not method calls), so you simply forgot to pass `$self` as a parameter.

```
my $object = {
    code1 => sub {
        print $_[0];
    },
    code2 => sub {
        return 'Hello, World!';
    },
    code3 => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        $self->{code1}->( $self, $self->{code2}->($self) );
    }
}; 
$object->{code3}->($object);
```

---

But I think you're trying to create JavaScript-like objects. You can start with the following:

```
package PrototypeObject;

sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = bless({}, $class);
   %$self = @_;
   return $self;
}

sub AUTOLOAD {
   my $self = shift;
   ( my $method = our $AUTOLOAD ) =~ s/^.*:://s;
   return $self->{$method}->($self, @_);
}

1;
```

```
use PrototypeObject qw( );

my $object = PrototypeObject->new(
    code1 => sub {
        print $_[1];
    },
    code2 => sub {
        return 'Hello, World!';
    },
    code3 => sub {
        my $self = shift;
        $self->code1( $self->code2() );
    }
); 

$object->code3();
```

Note that this will slow down your method calls as it must call AUTOLOAD before calling your method. This could be addressed by overloading the method call operator.

Check on CPAN. Someone might already have a more complete implementation.

Comment: I guess this is the purest approach I can use without resorting to wrappers. I was hoping there was language features allowing this kind of binding without object needing to pass itself to the coderef that is inside itself. eg, sub references act more like () => {} in javascript than function, and have no "this" unless you bless them into a package. I can imagine ways around this by creating a "Function package" that magically behaves the way I want via blessing hashes into it/or something similar, but I don't know enough Perl to express it let alone express it in a way that makes sense.

Comment: To be clear, I didn't "forget" to add the $object, I was wondering if there was a way to bind $object's refs to $object which is a ref so  that this behavior was "implicit".

Comment: It can't implicitly do a method call when you explicitly do a sub call. But see update

Comment: YES this is exactly what I wanted to know! Thanks!

Comment: that's a nice solution.

Comment: If you just return the function call without checking for existence in the hash, you get the error "Can't use an undefined value as a subroutine reference" and it points to the line in the AUTOLOAD, not where the call was made.

Comment: @Chas. Owens, How petty of you :( As the answer notes in two places, this is an incomplete solution. Highly incomplete, in fact. For starters, despite its name, it doesn't even support prototypes!! It was meant to illustrate the concept without bogging down the reader with irrelevant details. Again, one should be looking at CPAN for a more complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the exact syntax you want, but Perl 5 supports many ways of making method calls, including [method calls via strings](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Method-Call-Variations).  So you could say:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

{ package Foo;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new { bless {}, shift }

sub code1 { my $self = shift; print "$_[0]\n" };
sub code2 { "Hello, World!" }
sub code3 {
    my $self = shift;
    my $method1 = "code1";
    my $method2 = "code2";
    $self->$method1($self->$method2);
}

}

use strict;
use warnings;

my $o = Foo->new;

print "normal call\n";
$o->code3;

print "via string\n";
my $method = "code3";
$o->$method;
```

Also, remember that a [package's symbol table is a hash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html): `%Foo::`, so you can always go spelunking in there yourself:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

{ package Foo;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new { bless {}, shift }

sub code1 { my $self = shift; print "$_[0]\n" };
sub code2 { "Hello, World!" }
sub code3 {
    my $self = shift;
    my $method1 = "code1";
    my $method2 = "code2";
    $self->$method1($self->$method2);
}

}

use strict;
use warnings;

print $Foo::{code2}->(), "\n";
```

However, I would suggest having a really code reason for these techniques as it can make maintenance a nightmare (eg imaging trying to find all of the code calling `Foo::approved`, you can't just grep for "->approved" because the actual call is `->$state()`).

I just read the comments and noticed you said

> my concern with packages is that I can't seem to create packages at runtime, but I can create hash tables at runtime

Perl 5 does allow you to create packages at runtime.  In fact, depending on how you define runtime, you can do anything at runtime with [string `eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) as it reenters compile time when it is called. But there is also a pure-runtime method of manipulating the symbol tables with [typeglobs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

{ package Foo;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new { bless {}, shift }

}

use strict;
use warnings;

my $o = Foo->new;

# here we add functions at runtime to the package Foo
{
no warnings "once";
*Foo::code1 = sub { my $self = shift; print "$_[0]\n" };
*Foo::code2 = sub { "Hello, World!" };
*Foo::code3 = sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $method1 = "code1";
    my $method2 = "code2";
    $self->$method1($self->$method2);
};
}

$o->code3;
```

Because Perl 5 is object oriented (and not object based like JavaScript) these methods are attached to all Foo objects.  If you want individual objects have their own symbol tables, then I am there are certainly ways to do that.  Off the top of my head, [AUTOLOAD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Autoloading) comes to mind:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

{ package Foo;

use strict;
use Carp;
use warnings;

sub new {
    bless {
        symtab => {}
    }, shift
}

sub AUTOLOAD {
    my $self = shift;
    our $AUTOLOAD;
    my $method = $AUTOLOAD =~ s/.*:://r;

    my (undef, $file, $line) = caller();

    die "$method does not exist at $file line $line"
        unless exists $self->{symtab}{$method};

    $self->{symtab}{$method}->($self, @_);
}

sub DESTROY {} # prevent DESTROY method from being hijacked by AUTOLOAD

}

use v5.22;
use warnings;

my $o1 = Foo->new;
my $o2 = Foo->new;

$o1->{symtab}{inc} = sub { my $self = shift; $self->{i}++; };

$o1->inc;
$o1->inc;
$o1->inc;

say "inc called on o1 $o1->{i} times";

$o2->inc; #dies because we haven't defined inc for $o2 yet
```

Perl 5 is very flexible and will let you do just about anything you want (after all the motto is [TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)), but you should always keep in mind the future programmer tasked with maintaining your code who may want to hunt you down and wear your skin for doing some of these tricks.

This question has a definite [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/130036) feel.  It seems like you are trying to solve a problem in Perl 5 the same way you would have solved it in JavaScript.  While Perl 5 will let you do that (as I have demonstrated), there may be a more idiomatic way of achieving the same effect.  Can you describe what you are trying to do (not how you want to do it) in a different question and we can suggest the ways in which we would solve your problem.

Comment: Is there any reading I can read to see a list of differences between a package(something I don't really understand), and a hashes(something I don't understand less)? packages are really strange to me; I know how to go through keys in a hash, but how do I go through members of a package? I know how to check types of hash members, but how do I check types of package members?

Comment: Another thing is I have no idea how to check type of a "sub a{}" non reference that is in another package, or how to add a sub b{} non reference to another package from outside the package b is defined into(is this even possible?)

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer, this is far from idiomatic question, I was mainly interested in how to reproduce JavaScript-like evaluatable-module behavior "Perl Object Notation"(eg read .pl file with an anonymous function that returns a list or a hash, and eval it into the ref type and use it to create objects using its internal "coderefs"). Perl is available on all unix-like systems, but nodejs isn't so I want to know how much concepts in js can be expressed with Perl).

Comment: The [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html) and [perlobj](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) documentation goes pretty in depth about modules/packages.  Hashes are covered in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).  You may be better served getting a copy of [Programming Perl](https://amzn.com/0596004923) though.

Comment: I don't understand your "another thing" quesiton.

Comment: I meant `sub foo { print 'hi'; }` Is it possible to check the type of foo? and if its possible to define a  `sub A::foo { print 'hi'; }` from outside the package A, e.g. assign A::foo as a sub(not a subref) from main package.

Comment: Perl 5 does not provide a good way to serialize methods.  Data serializes just fine (use [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON/lib/JSON.pm), [YAML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAML-LibYAML/lib/YAML/XS.pod), etc), but methods are trickier.  The biggest problem is closures.  There is no way make that work right in any language I know of.

Comment: serializing objects back is something JavaScript doesn't support out of the box neither "uneval" is not universally supported, but I have successfully implemented it with reading each key in the object and recursively parsed it based on its type(in js, functions have a toString which returns the function code so you can put an object back into the file after, creating "living" modules). Sadly Perl does not support getting string representation of code "back" from runtime, but my issue was based on evaluation rather than stringification, which perl does equally well.

Comment: Yes, and it is literally that syntax: "sub PACKAGE::SUBNAME {}". You can say that anywhere and it will create a funciton named SUBNAME in PACKAGE. You can even redefine existing subroutines (but you might want to say `no warnings "redefine"` first or you will get a warning).  If you want to redefine a function, but still call the existing function, you can grab the old coderef with a typeglob first: `my $old = *PACKAGE::SUBNAME{CODE};` you can then call it just like a normal coderef: `$old->();`.

Comment: Well, Perl 5 does sort of allow you to get the code back as a string.  You can translate the opcodes back into readable Perl 5.  Take a look at [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html)'s $Data::Dumper::Deparse option: `perl -MData::Dumper -E '$Data::Dumper::Deparse = 1; print Dumper sub { my $foo = 5; say $foo }'`.  The downside is it can't fixup closures and there is some code loss/translation due to the compile phase.

Comment: It's just really nice to be able to do stuff like "http://hastebin.com/jabanuxeyu.coffee" (I call it jace since it's unsafe json). JS also doesn't stringify to perfectly evaluated js and needs have brackets added around it. Perl equivalent is http://hastebin.com/domevifege.pl "closures". Which seem easier to serialize back than packages. The idea would be something like requirepl: http://hastebin.com/udaqeyifin.pl.

Comment: Ok this is really cool: I made a repository to collect what I have so far: https://github.com/dmitrymakhnin/nodepl.

Comment: Owers oooh so that's what * does, you can indeed redefine subs by setting `*mysub = sub { print "hi"; };` or get it's reference by `$a = *mysub;`. No idea why ref($a) isn't CODE though.

Comment: Actually, you do want to redirect DESTROY too in this case

Comment: Sort of, `*mysub` is a typeglob.  That is why `ref` says GLOB for the type.  Typeglobs can be used to manipulate the symbol table for any of the other types.  So `$mysub`, `@mysub`, `%mysub`, and `&mysub` (in addition to some others) are all accessible through `*mysub`.  If you want just the coderef, you use the [THING syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) (that is its actual name): `perl -E 'sub Foo::bar {}; say ref *Foo::bar{CODE}`.  Likewise, you can get at the arrayref with `*Foo::bar{ARRAY}` and so on.

Comment: @ikegami Doesn't that depend on what you want `DESTROY` to do?  I usually don't have special code in `DESTROY`, so I don't want the `AUTOLOAD` function grabbing it.  You could always create the object with `{ symtab => { DESTROY => sub {}, } }` instead of making it globally do nothing.  That way if a given instance of Foo needed to do something special, it could replace the default `DESTROY` method.

Comment: The "you could always" was instead of defining it as subroutine.

Comment: @ikegami what benefit is there to handling the DESTROY as a special case in the AUTOLOAD? As far as I can see it should either be treated like the other methods (except that is has to be predeclared in the `new`), or it should be moved to its own method (like I originally did).  Adding it to AUTOLOAD as just a `return if $method eq "DESTROY";`  would be pointless code with no benefit.

Comment: @ikegami I don't understand your argument. Having a DESTROY sub defined just means `->can("DESTROY")` will return a true value.  What is so horrible about that? This isn't like creating a sub named count that a subclass might have a different meaning for.  By your argument there shouldn't even be a new method.  It should be a special case of AUTOLOAD too.  That would make even more sense since the meaning of new is by convention, but the meaning of DESTROY is part of the language.

Comment: @ikegami "Namespace pollution is a bad thing" without proving there is namespace pollution isn't an argument. It is parroting something you heard once.  Show me why having a DESTROY method is namespace pollution.  It can't conflict with any other DESTROY method in a subclass (a DESTROY method has only one meaning in Perl 5).  There are no exports from this package, so it can't pollute other namespaces.  The new function is more pollution than DESTROY, but apparently you have "no thoughts on the matter".  Why do you have thoughts on the matter of DESTROY?

Comment: Re "*Show me why having a DESTROY method is namespace pollution*", Adding something to a namespace whether the user of that namespace wants it or not is the very definition of namespace pollution. /// Re "*without proving there is namespace pollution*", huh? Since we're talking about the case where there is namespace pollution, it makes no sense to try to prove there is namespace pollution. Or rather, it's trivially easy.

Comment: Re *"...a really code reason..."*: Do you mean *"...a really good reason..."*?